# Mongo indexes for updates/inserts of fields

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to insert a new field for all of the documents in the collection.
I have an ascending index on "user_id" field.

a) In order to benefit from indexes, should the field being updated/inserted be included/convered by a index ?
b) Also, is hash index more performant in this case given that I dont do any range operations.

```
db.collA.update(  { user_id: 123 }
                , { $set : { newfield : "something" } }
                , { multi:true} )
```

Comment: Would be kind of useless to put the updated field into the index unless you only ever expect to update the index and never the actual on disk document. As for hashed indexes I do not see how they will help here, even if you were using hashed indexes MongoDB would still do a internal range query to find the exact value going through parts of the btree whose value is within the range of this id (say range 1-1000 fit your 123) and then would do a type of binary search to find the exact value. Using a hash index might load the entire index into RAM instead of the segment you need.

Comment: thanks. Was trying to put together random things i read on mongo indexes. You should just make this an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: I may have missed something that changed within the last couple of versions about hashing indexes so I'll see if anyone has some nugget I overlooked

Answer (score 0):

Answering part A of your question:
No. Inserting or updating the indexed attribute of an existing document can actually cause performance problems for an index. If you're going to do this in a large batch, you should probably re-index or repair after the operation.

Part B:
No. The standard index type covers this use case just fine. If a "user_id" truly identifies a document you may consider making it the "_id" of the document, however, this is a somewhat advanced design decision and comes with implications for the collection (both positive and negative).